# Polymer content selection dom-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have the following polymer element.

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[items]]">
        <paper-item>
            <span>[[item]]</span>
        </paper-item>
    </template>
</dom-module>
```

Expected to be used as

```
<my-element items="[[items]]">
</my-element>
```

This will repeat the hardcoded span. But is it possible for the host to supply the rendering component as well. So instead of `span` they can provide whats going to be repeated.

```
<my-element items="[[items]]">
    <div>
        <div>[[item.name]]</div>
        <div>[[item.address]]</div>
    </div>
</my-element>
```

Tried content selection doesn't seem to repeat the selected element.

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[items]]">
        <paper-item>
            <content select="element"></content>
        </paper-item>
    </template>
</dom-module>
<my-element items="[[items]]">
    <div class="element">
        <div>[[item.name]]</div>
        <div>[[item.address]]</div>
    </div>
</my-element>
```

Appreciate any help or directions on this.

Answer (score 2):

If multiple `<content>` elements with the same `select` value are added all elements are projected to the first element with a matching selector. You need to find a different strategy.